# subprocess.Popenのstdoutとstderrをリアルタイムに取得する

Tags: python, python3, linux, posix, python-multiprocessing

pythonの `subprocess.Popen` で子プロセスのstdoutとstderrの内容を加工した上で、親のstdout、stderrにそれぞれリアルタイムに、且つ順番通りに出力したいです。
例えば、以下の `hoge.sh` を `実行例` のように実行したいです。

hoge.sh

```sh
echo yes1
echo no1  >&2
echo yes21
echo yes22
echo no2  >&2
```

fuga.py:

```py
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen(['bash', 'hoge.sh'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, ...)

~~  p.stdoutは先頭に"out:"を、p.stderrは"err:"をつけて出力 ~~

p.wait()
```

実行例:

```
$ python fuga.py                ※加工されたstdout stderr が順番通り出力される
out: yes1
err: no1
out: yes21
out: yes22
err: no2
$ python fuga.py > /dev/null    ※加工されたstderr のみ出力される
err: no1
err: no2
```

---

ネットで見つけた以下のコードが今の所もっとも目的に近いのですが、こちらのコードではstdoutとstderrの順番が保証されません。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import PIPE
from threading import Thread


def read_stream(in_file, out_file):
    for line in in_file:
        print(line.strip(), file=out_file, flush=True)

p = subprocess.Popen("./test_stream.py", stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
Thread(target=read_stream, args=(p.stdout, sys.stdout)).start()
Thread(target=read_stream, args=(p.stderr, sys.stderr)).start()
```

出力結果: （stdoutとstderrの順番が入れ替わることがある）

```
out: yes1
err: no1
out: yes21
err: no2
out: yes22
```

---

お力添えのほど何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

> stdoutとstderrの順番が入れ替わることがある

アプリ(bash) の 入力、出力が バッファリングされている可能性があって
その バッファを アプリ側が 明示的に flush するような 起動オプションがないか調べる
https://gist.github.com/riywo/874011

bash 自体に そのようなオプションはなさそうなので、
linux の標準出力のバッファサイズを小さくする方法

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 <command>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847897/in-bash-how-can-i-force-a-flush-of-an-incomplete-line-printed-to-the-terminal

を実行してみる。

あとは read_stream の中で 文字列処理を複数スレッドで行うと思うので
この時に順番が入れ替わる可能性があるので、それは アプリ側で対策する。

等が考えられます。

試してないので違っているかもしれません。
参考までに・・。